# Why does the same regex work in Google Analytics Segments but not Filters?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, filtering, advanced-segments

I am using the following regex to exclude spam sites:

`(social\-buttons\.com|darodar\.com|free\-share\-buttons\.com|buy\-cheap\-online\.info|Get\-Free\-Traffic\-Now\.com|hol\.es|hulfingtonpost\.com|googlsucks\.com)`

When I added a **Segment** with this filter, I get the desired results. However, when I created a **View** with a **Filter**, it didn't filter `buy-cheap-online.info`. I suspect that as the days go on, it will not filter the other sites. (I understand that Filters are not applied retroactively.)

Why doesn't the same regex work in both **Segments** and **Filters**?

Comment: FYI you don't need to backslash escape hyphens in a regex (unless they occur in the _middle_ of a character class and you wish to match a literal hyphen.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression should work fine on both is strange that it doesn't for filters. I tested here https://regex101.com/

Probably the filter hasn't started working yet. **Filters may take up to 24hrs** for start showing in your stats https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6046990?hl=en

**GA allows simpler syntax for basic expression**, dots and hyphens don't need to be escaped you can write your expression like this

```
social-buttons.com|darodar.com|free-share-buttons.com|buy-cheap-online.info|Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com|hol.es|hulfingtonpost.com|googlsucks.com
```

It will work the same and save you some characters

**UPDATE:** This Expression should be used with **Campaign source** on the *Field type*. More information here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. What concerned me was that I click "Verify Filter" to see if any changes *would* occur after it went into effect, and it said no. I've reapplied the updated filter that you and @w3d recommended and will check back in a couple days.

Comment: I've waited a week to collect data with the filter; it does not work. Using `social-buttons.com|darodar.com|free-share-buttons.com|buy-cheap-online.info|Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com|hol.es|hulfingtonpost.com|googlsucks.com` still lets through `site3.free-share-buttons.com` and `www.Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com`. It may let the others in if I give it more time.

Comment: Matt are you using Exclude > Campaign Source on the filter field?

Comment: I am using **Request URI** as the filter field. (Screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/li8q0y3av/)

Comment: The *Request URI*  is the **part of the URL after the hostname** for example `somehost.com/some-page`, the request URI is /some-page, so that's why your filter is not working. Change it for **Campaign Source** and it will work, here is more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362